# Getting one company from two tables

Tags: python, performance, sqlalchemy, fastapi

Currently I'm working with ***fastapi***, ***sqlalchemy*** to connect to multiple databases. It checks `params` to ensure it has `company_name`, then will return the current table in that database, but if no `company_name` is set then it will return one record from each Table in the 2 databases.

```
class Params(BaseModel):
    company_name: str | None


def multiple_db(db, model):
    # return data from db TEST1
    ret = db.query(model).all()

    # return data from db TEST2
    ret1 = db.query(model).all()

    return ret, ret1


def db_query(db: Session, params, model):
    if params.company_name == "TEST1":
        return db.query(model)

    if params.company_name == "TEST2":
        return db.query(model)


@app.get("/")
def get_all(params: Params = Depends(), db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    if params.company_name == None:
        ret, ret1 = multiple_db(db, MODEL1, MODEL2)
        return {"ret": ret, "ret2": ret1}

    else:
        ret = db_query(db, params, MODEL1).all()
        return ret
```

Is there a way to improve this code?

Answer (score 2):

## usual type hinting

```
    company_name: str | None
```

This is a perfectly nice declaration, which you can leave as-is.
But prefer `Optional` when using a modern cPython interpreter.

```
from typing import Optional
...
    company_name: Optional[str]
```

Hinting in the python community has been an evolving practice.
Let's take `Y` to be the type `None`.
Despite the [goal](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/#abstract) of

> There should be one -- and preferably only one -- obvious way to do it.

we have the `Union[X, Y]`, `X | Y`, and `Optional[X]` synonyms.
The first is a verbose historical artifact which is discouraged in newly
authored source code -- prefer the second, e.g. `float | complex`.
In the special case of `Y` being `None`, prefer Optional,
as an aid to human cognition.
It's just how folks reading your code will think about the parameter.
We see similar effects in other languages,
such as using `?` punctuation to guard against a null de-ref.
It's technically precise notation for the machine,
which doesn't get in the way of reasoning about
the happy-path of an algorithm.

Consider making the name mandatory (that is, a varchar which is NOT NULL).

EDIT

There's a lot of "six versus half-dozen" when deciding to express a type
as `Optional[x]` versus `x | None`.
Prior to [python 3.10](https://peps.python.org/pep-0604)
there wasn't much of a choice -- who would want a clunky `Union[x, None]` ?
Apparently I've been working with a lot of pre-3.10 hinted source code.
I withdraw the `company_name` remark.

I defer to Martijn Pieters, who
[advises](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51710151)
to prefer `x | None`.

---

## use meaningful identifiers

```
    return ret, ret1
```

Those are not great names,
especially since database TEST2 is associated with `ret1`.
Prefer `return rows1, rows2` or something more verbose
that mentions the DB names.
Same issue crops up when you `return {"ret": ret, "ret2": ret1}`.
Definitely choose a more informative identifier than `"ret"`
when defining a public API which web clients will consume.

Also, the code appears to query same DB twice,
despite the comment's claim that we query a pair of databases.
Similar remark further down within `def db_query`.

Type hinting the signature wouldn't hurt.

We appear to return a pair of generators, which can be confusing
to a caller that anticipates getting a container which can be
scanned more than once. Consider wrapping the `.all()` result
with `list( ... .all() )`

---

## mutable default arg

```
def get_all(params: Params = Depends(), db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
```

OP omits the import / definition for `Depends`.

[Avoid](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas)
evaluating such expressions at `import` time.
Prefer a default value of `None`,
and then assign `db = db or Depends(get_db)`
down in the method body.
That will be evaluated at run time rather than at import time,
side stepping a whole category of tricky bugs.
Even if it doesn't matter in *this* particular code,
avoid the bad habit.
Use a linter to help you out.
For example `pylint` will report that as "W0102: Dangerous default value".

```
    if params.company_name == None:
```

nit: prefer `is` over `==` when testing for that particular singleton.
Again, rely on a linter, which might report "C0121 (singleton-comparison)".

EDIT

Hmmm, I use sqlalchemy a lot, but not fastapi.
It appears the omitted import was

```
from fastapi import Depends
```

The [docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/#declare-the-dependency-in-the-dependant)
seem to encourage mutable default args.
I am unfamiliar with the fastapi details,
and do not yet have an opinion on best way to express that.
Sticking to what the docs recommend seems best ATM.

---

## callsite should match signature

```
        ... = multiple_db(db, MODEL1, MODEL2)
```

This appears to be correct, in the sense
that it matches Author's Intent revealed in the comments.
It specifies one more parameter than the `def` signature supports.

---

## add hints

```
def db_query(db: Session, params, model):
```

Thank you for the `Session` type hint.

This signature should end with `->` and
the intended return type.
If it did, then
[mypy](https://pypi.org/project/mypy)
would helpfully tell you about the
implicit `return None` at end of function.

If caller didn't pass in one of the two valid values,
then better to `raise` a fatal error than silently
return a value of incorrect type.

---

## relational design

Consider defining a VIEW that offers UNION ALL of
the rows of both tables.

Then all queries are against the view,
and your WHERE clause determines how many tables
participate in forming the result set.

---

This codebase does not appear to achieve its design goals.

I would not be willing to delegate or accept maintenance tasks on it.

Comment: I work on several typed python codebases, and even those that still use py3.8 use `from __future__ import annotations` and `SomeThing | None` in type hints. There is some sort of consensus in python typing community that `... | None` is usually a better alternative to `Optional`: it doesn't require extra import, lines up with chained unions (would you prefer `int | str | None` or `Optional[int | str]`?) This is (weakly) advised in [PEP604](https://peps.python.org/pep-0604/#simplified-syntax) (they call it "simplified syntax" for `Optional` case).

Comment: @SUTerliakov, thanks for the comment. It prompted an answer update.